# Load Dataset Columns From Xsd using ReadXmlSchema

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, dataset

I've tried to load dataset columns from a schema with ReadXmlSchema method.
It's working but 0 column loads. And I could not see any problem with the xsd file. Here my xsd file:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Tip.xsd" xmlns:ns4="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Risk.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://tempuri.org/Ek.xsd" xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/Form.xsd" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Form.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Tip.xsd" schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Tip.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Risk.xsd" schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Risk.xsd"/>
<xsd:import  namespace="http://tempuri.org/Ek.xsd" schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Ek.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="Form">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Veri">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Satir" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="SiraNo" type="ns3:Sayi15"/>
<xsd:element name="KrediIslemHesapNo" type="ns4:Karakter60"/>
<xsd:element name="MusteriNo" type="ns5:Karakter25"/>
<xsd:element name="VergiNo" type="ns4:Sayi11" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="Adi" type="ns3:Karakter255"/>
<xsd:element name="UlkeKodu" type="ns3:UlkeKodu"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemTuru" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element name="TarafKodu" type="ns3:IslemTarafKodu"/>
<xsd:element name="MusteriRiskSinif" type="ns4:MusterininRiskSinifi2"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemTutarAnaparaTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemTutarFaizTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemTutarToplamTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemOrijinalParaKodu" type="ns3:ParaKodu2"/>
<xsd:element name="ParaKoduEndeks" type="ns3:ParaKoduEndeks" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="MKIhracciUnvan" type="ns3:Karakter255"/>
<xsd:element name="MKISINKodu" type="ns3:Karakter12"/>
<xsd:element name="PiyasaFiyatTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
<xsd:element name="MKParaKodu" type="ns3:ParaKodu2"/>
<xsd:element name="MKVade" type="xsd:date" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemVade" type="xsd:date"/>
<xsd:element name="Portfoy" type="ns4:Portfoy2"/>
<xsd:element name="BilancoDeger" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
<xsd:element name="NominalDeger" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
<xsd:element name="AlacakVolAyarKatsayi" type="ns4:Yuzde5_3" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="KurVolAyarKatsayi" type="ns4:Yuzde5_3" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="TeminatVolAyarKatsayi" type="ns4:Yuzde5_3" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="KarsiTarafRiskAgirlik" type="ns3:Sayi4" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="TeminatRiskAgirlik" type="ns3:Sayi4" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="RAV" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemTHPKodu" type="ns3:Karakter8"/>
<xsd:element name="MKTHPKodu" type="ns3:Karakter8" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="MKSinif" type="ns4:MKIslemSinif"/>
<xsd:element name="IslemSinif" type="ns4:MKIslemSinif"/>
<xsd:element name="EmanetDurumu" type="ns3:Karakter255"/>
<xsd:element name="IlaveTeminat" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element name="KRATSonraRAV" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu1" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu2" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu3" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu4" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu1" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu2" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu3" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu4" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="Gun" type="ns4:Gun" use="required" fixed="1"/>
<xsd:attribute name="Ay" type="ns4:Ay" use="required"/>
<xsd:attribute name="Yil" type="ns3:Sayi4" use="required"/>
<xsd:attribute name="FormKodu" type="ns3:Karakter7" use="required" fixed="RT100AS"/>
<xsd:attribute name="KurulusKodu" type="ns5:Sayi3" use="required"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Could someone please tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> It's working...

That's not believable.

> ...but 0 column loads.

Now that is believable.

An immediately obvious problem is that the URLs given by the `schemaLocations` in the `xsd:import`s of your XSD redirect to www.bing.com.  Before anything else, you'll have to resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

xsd namespace doesn't like nested tags.  Also you need a single root element.  Made changes to get xml to read.  Not sure if it is what you really need.

code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
        }

    }



}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root xsd:schema="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001" xmlns:ns3="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Tip.xsd" xmlns:ns4="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Risk.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://tempuri.org/Ek.xsd" xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/Form.xsd" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Form.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Tip.xsd" schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Tip.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Risk.xsd" schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Ortak_Risk.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import  namespace="http://tempuri.org/Ek.xsd" schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Ek.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="Form">
    <xsd:complex>
      <xsd:complexSequence>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:elementSequence name="Veri">
              <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:restrictionType base="xsd:anyType">
                    <xsd:sequenceType>
                      <xsd:table name="Satir" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:elementAttribute>
                          <xsd:complexAttribute>
                            <xsd:restrictionAttribute base="xsd:anyType">
                              <xsd:sequenceAttribute>
                                <xsd:attribute name="SiraNo" type="ns3:Sayi15"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KrediIslemHesapNo" type="ns4:Karakter60"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MusteriNo" type="ns5:Karakter25"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="VergiNo" type="ns4:Sayi11" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="Adi" type="ns3:Karakter255"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="UlkeKodu" type="ns3:UlkeKodu"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemTuru" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="TarafKodu" type="ns3:IslemTarafKodu"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MusteriRiskSinif" type="ns4:MusterininRiskSinifi2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemTutarAnaparaTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemTutarFaizTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemTutarToplamTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemOrijinalParaKodu" type="ns3:ParaKodu2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="ParaKoduEndeks" type="ns3:ParaKoduEndeks" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKIhracciUnvan" type="ns3:Karakter255"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKISINKodu" type="ns3:Karakter12"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="PiyasaFiyatTLKarsilik" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKParaKodu" type="ns3:ParaKodu2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKVade" type="xsd:date" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemVade" type="xsd:date"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="Portfoy" type="ns4:Portfoy2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="BilancoDeger" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="NominalDeger" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="AlacakVolAyarKatsayi" type="ns4:Yuzde5_3" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KurVolAyarKatsayi" type="ns4:Yuzde5_3" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="TeminatVolAyarKatsayi" type="ns4:Yuzde5_3" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KarsiTarafRiskAgirlik" type="ns3:Sayi4" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="TeminatRiskAgirlik" type="ns3:Sayi4" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="RAV" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemTHPKodu" type="ns3:Karakter8"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKTHPKodu" type="ns3:Karakter8" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKSinif" type="ns4:MKIslemSinif"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IslemSinif" type="ns4:MKIslemSinif"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="EmanetDurumu" type="ns3:Karakter255"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="IlaveTeminat" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KRATSonraRAV" type="ns5:Yuzde14_2" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu1" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu2" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu3" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="KarsiTarafDerecelendirmeNotu4" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu1" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu2" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu3" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                                <xsd:attribute name="MKDerecelendirmeNotu4" type="ns5:Karakter25" nillable="true"/>
                              </xsd:sequenceAttribute>
                            </xsd:restrictionAttribute>
                          </xsd:complexAttribute>
                        </xsd:elementAttribute>
                      </xsd:table>
                    </xsd:sequenceType>
                  </xsd:restrictionType>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:complexContent>
            </xsd:elementSequence>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="Gun" type="ns4:Gun" use="required" fixed="1"/>
          <xsd:attribute name="Ay" type="ns4:Ay" use="required"/>
          <xsd:attribute name="Yil" type="ns3:Sayi4" use="required"/>
          <xsd:attribute name="FormKodu" type="ns3:Karakter7" use="required" fixed="RT100AS"/>
          <xsd:attribute name="KurulusKodu" type="ns5:Sayi3" use="required"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexSequence>
    </xsd:complex>
  </xsd:element>
  <!--</xsd:schema>-->
</Root>
```

Comment: *xsd namespace doesn't like nested tags.*   I cannot imagine an interpretation of that statement that makes sense.

Comment: *Also you need a single root element.*   OP has a single root element; there simply is no indentation to show it.

Comment: Finally, why would you replace OP's root `xsd:schema` element with a contrived `Root` element?

Comment: Try the following : In vs from menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Paste OP original XML into new view making sure only one xml identification line exist.  Then open the vs error list.  You will see lots of warnings.  Then repeat with my xml.  The original xml file will not import while my changes do import.  There are many ways of fixing the original xml.  It you have a better way of fixing the xml let me know.

Comment: You've disregarded all three of the problems I raised with your answer, merely to describe a procedure that completely obfuscates OP's `xsd:import` problem by blowing away his `xsd:schema` root element so that VS no longer thinks that this is an XSD.   **Sorry, but this answer is so utterly wrong that there's no saving it; it should be deleted.**

Comment: How would you fix the xml?